# Find continuous function $f$ with $f(\mathbb{Q}) = 0$ and $f(\mathbb{Q}+ \sqrt{2}) = 1$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Urysohn's Lemma approximates indicator functions with continuous functions.

> Let $X$ be a **normal** topological space.  For every disjoint pair of closed sets $A,B$ there is a continuous function $f: X \to [0,1]$ with $f(A) \equiv 1$ and $f(B) \equiv 0$.

I think $\mathbb{R}$ is normal.

- So we can find a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ with $f(\mathbb{Q}) = 0$ and $f(\mathbb{Q}+ \sqrt{2}) = 1$.
- Or we can find disjoint open neighborhoods of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q} + \sqrt{2}$.

The first one seems possible but the  second one seems impossible.

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ is not a closed subspace of $\Bbb R$. In fact $\overline{\Bbb Q} = \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f,g\,\colon X\to Y$ be continuous functions and $Y$ Hausdorff space. It is known result that for any dense subset $D\subseteq X$, we have $f|_D = g|_D \implies f = g$.

Assume that there exists continuous $f$ such that $f(\mathbb Q) = 0$ and $f( \mathbb Q + \sqrt 2) = 1$, and let $g = 0$ (where $f$ and $g$ are real functions). We have that $f|_\mathbb Q = g|_\mathbb Q$, which by upper remark implies $f = g$ on whole $\mathbb R$, since $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$. Contradiction.

For the second part, take any $x\in\mathbb Q + \sqrt 2\subseteq \mathbb R$ and any open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$. By density of $\mathbb Q$, we have that $U$ contains an element of $\mathbb Q$. Thus, $\mathbb Q$ cannot be separated from $\mathbb Q+\sqrt 2$ by open subsets. In fact, no point in $\mathbb R$ can be separated from $\mathbb Q$ by open subsets. This is what density means.